# Inconsistent bonus reputation from linking Stack Exchange accounts

Tags: support, reputation, linked-accounts

I linked my Stack Overflow account with new accounts on Meta Stack Overflow, Server Fault and Super User.

On Meta Stack Overflow and Server Fault I got +100 reputation points from linking account, but on Super User I didn't get it.

Why is that?

Comment: Try unlinking it and linking it to SO first, and then the others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clear all associations using the button, and then re-link.